# Check Wireless State in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I want to connect some signal to my slot to notify me when wireless connection disconnect or connect in Qt
base on documentation I Use `onlineStateChanged` signal that define in `QNetworkConfigurationManager` class base on this link [link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qnetworkconfigurationmanager.html)

my code does not work on windows ( not test on Linux) when turning off or turn on wifi but **sometimes** when turn of my Bluetooth or Ethernet signal trigger
my simple code is

```
QNetworkConfigurationManager *ncm = new QNetworkConfigurationManager();
ChangeEvent *myhandler = new ChangeEvent ();
QObject::connect(ncm, SIGNAL(onlineStateChanged(bool)), myhandler, SLOT(myslot(bool)));
```

Comment: Shouldn't you create the ncm first? like: ncm= new QNetworkConfigurationManager(this);

Comment: no need in Addition other signal work properly but only this signal does not work for me

Comment: I think this is a bug, report it.

Answer (score 0):

I connect signal `onlineStateChanged` to a slot and seems it's working.

I test this in Windows 7, Qt 5.9.0:

```
QNetworkConfigurationManager *ncm = new QNetworkConfigurationManager();
connect(ncm, &QNetworkConfigurationManager::onlineStateChanged, this, &MainWindow::configurationStateChanged);
```

Slot:

```
void MainWindow::configurationStateChanged()
{
    qDebug()<< "online State Changed";
}
```

This is a sample project for your question on [github download here.](https://github.com/FarhadProfessional/WiFi)

Comment: Is it work for Wi-Fi switching?

Answer (score 0):

I finally find solution
this signal call when your accessibility to internet connect or disconnect
I disconnect my wireless but my VMware connections was connected and because of that slot function does not call
I disconnect that VMware connections and every thing ok